# Assigning variables instead of direct references inside a loop resulting in different results

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I have been trying for the past 2 hours to figure out why the following two methods are giving different results. Both of them are methods that take an integer array, remove any consecutive duplicates in it and put a "-1" at the end for each duplicate removed.

Method 1 gives correct output, while method 2 turns into an infinite loop.

```
//Method 1
private static void smoosh1(int[] ints) {

    for (int i=0; i<ints.length-1; i++) {
        while (ints[i] == ints[i+1] && ints[i] != -1) {
            for (int x=i; x<ints.length-1; x++) {
                ints[x] = ints[x+1]; }
            ints[ints.length-1] = -1;
            }
        }
    }




//Method 2
public static void smoosh(int[] ints) {

  for (int i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {

      int curVal=ints[i];
     int nextVal=ints[i+1];

      while (curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1) {

          for (int x = i; x < ints.length-1; x++) {
              ints[x] = ints[x + 1];

          }
          ints[ints.length-1] = -1;
      }
       }
```

Kindly explain to me the reason why declaring the variables inside the loop is affecting the output. Thanks.

Note:- This problem is from Part 1, Homework 3 of MOOC 61B at Berkeley.
       Link:- https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/hw/hw3/

Comment: curVal and nextValNever changes in the while loop so the output of `curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1` is always same. In your case `true`.

Comment: Indeed, it seems you might need an `if` instead of a `while` , so changing the `while (curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1)` to `if (curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1)` should do the trick for code ...

Answer (score 0):

In order for the second snippet to behave the same as the first snippet, the `while` loop must modify the values of `curVal` and `nextVal` in each iteration:

```
public static void smoosh(int[] ints) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {
        int curVal=ints[i];
        int nextVal=ints[i+1];
        while (curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1) {
            for (int x = i; x < ints.length-1; x++) {
                ints[x] = ints[x + 1];
            }
            ints[ints.length-1] = -1;
            curVal=ints[i];
            nextVal=ints[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise the vaule of the expression `curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1` always remains the same, and the while loop either never executes or never terminates.

Answer (score 0):

One you get in the while loop (consecutive duplicate found in the array) you will never get out, because the curVal and nextVal never change.
I suugest you to write a debug line like this :

```
//Method 2
public static void smoosh(int[] ints) {

  for (int i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {

      int curVal=ints[i];
     int nextVal=ints[i+1];

      while (curVal == nextVal && curVal !=-1) {
System.out.println(curVal + " "+ nextVal);

          for (int x = i; x < ints.length-1; x++) {
              ints[x] = ints[x + 1];

          }
          ints[ints.length-1] = -1;
      }
       }
```